# Arduino and Interrupts: Fast way to get pin values

Tags: c++, arduino, interrupts

I use an [Arduino Uno](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno) and already set it up to work with interrupts on digital pins 2, 3, 4 and 5 according to an explanation[1](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno) I found.

`void setup()` contains the following code to setup the interrupts.

```
  //Endable Interrupts for PCIE2 Arduino Pins (D0-7)
  PCICR |= (1<<PCIE2);

  //Setup pins 2,3,4,5
  PCMSK2 |= (1<<PCINT18);
  PCMSK2 |= (1<<PCINT19);
  PCMSK2 |= (1<<PCINT20);
  PCMSK2 |= (1<<PCINT21);

  //Trigger Interrupt on rising edge
  MCUCR = (1<<ISC01) | (1<<ISC01);
```

And now, the ISR( PCINT2_vect ) function is triggered on every interrupt. That works like a charm. My question is, what is the best/fastest way to find out, which pin was triggered?

I found something in *[Re: Is better to use ISR(PCINT2_vect) or attachInterrupt on pins 2, 3?](http://www.me.ucsb.edu/~me170c/Code/How_to_Enable_Interrupts_on_ANY_pin.pdf)*, but I do not understand the code and it does not work out of the box. But it looks impressive...

What is the solution?

[2] http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php/topic,72496.15.html#lastPost

Edit:

At the moment, I am reading the pin state from the from the input pin register:

```
  if (PIND & 0b00000100)
    Serial.println( "PIN 2" );
  if (PIND & 0b00001000)
    Serial.println( "PIN 3" );
  if (PIND & 0b00010000)
    Serial.println( "PIN 4" );
  if (PIND & 0b00100000)
    Serial.println( "PIN 5" );
```

In the end, I want to count the interrupts on the pins.
But how can I assure, that there are no counted twice?

Comment: At electronics, more people have probably messed around with Arduinos and other electronic things.

Comment: If you think, the question should be over there, flag it. I solved my login problems.

Comment: @Earlz:  This is a programming question, so **it's on-topic**.  The fact that it's for a hobbyist platform is irrelevant; see the [hundreds of other arduino questions on stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arduino) for reference.

Answer (score 5):

I have a first solution myself, but i could not test the reliability as the hardware is not finished jet.

First I added oldPins and tickCount as global variables:

```
static byte oldPins = 0;
volatile unsigned int tickCount[4] = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
```

And thats how I solved the ISR at the moment. Better solutions are more than welcome.

```
ISR( PCINT2_vect ) {
  //Read values from digital pins 2 to 7
  const byte actPins = PIND;
  //Match this values agaist the oldPins bitmask (XOR and AND for raising edge)
  const byte setPins = (oldPins ^ actPins) & actPins;

  if (setPins & 0b00000100)
    tickCount[0]++;
  if (setPins & 0b00001000)
    tickCount[1]++;
  if (setPins & 0b00010000)
    tickCount[2]++;
  if (setPins & 0b00100000)
    tickCount[3]++;

  oldPins = actPins;
}
```

Comment: If you are updating tickCount[] in an ISR, you should be declaring it with the 'volatile' type qualifier.

Comment: I updated the code inside the answer. For more information see the arduino documentation: http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Volatile